# Append Member/Column to PSObject

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to add an extra member to an object in PowerShell without creating a new object and looping.

Typically when I run a script it will be again a list of servers and I want to append some extra information against the data I'm returning but I can't find a way to do it without creating a new PSObject and looping through the existing object and adding the extra member row by row (simplified example below)

```
$FileList = get-childitem | Select-Object Name, DirectoryName
$FileListOBJ = @()

foreach ($item in $FileList)
{    
    $Temp = New-Object PSObject 
    $Temp | Add-Member NoteProperty ServerName "XServerName"
    $Temp | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName $item.Name
    $Temp | Add-Member NoteProperty Directory $item.DirectoryName    

    $FileListOBJ += $Temp
}

$FileListOBJ
```

Is there a way to do it along these lines ...

```
get-childitem | Select-Object "ServerName", Name, DirectoryName
```

The above code creates the extra Member but I haven't been able to find a way to fill the additional member with the details I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use a *calculated property* (more about them [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)):

```
get-childitem | Select-Object @{l="ServerName"; e={"XServerName"}}, Name, DirectoryName
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be a simpler way of doing it

Answer (score 3):

you can also create a new object without the add-member calls:

```
$FileList = get-childitem | Select-Object Name, DirectoryName
$FileListOBJ = @()
foreach ($item in $FileList)
{    
    $FileListOBJ += [PSCustomObject]@{ServerName="ServerName";FileName=$item.Name;Directory=$item.DirectoryName}
}

$FileListOBJ
```